# image pre-processing for image classification and semantic segmentation

Tags: computer-vision, tensorflow, deep-learning, caffe, keras

In terms of training deep learning models for different types of image-related works, such as image classification, semantic segmentation, what kind of pre-processing works need to be performed?

For instance, if I want to train a network for semantic segmentation, do I need to scale the image value (normally represented as an nd-array) to `[0,1]` range, or keep it as `[0,255]` range? Thanks.

Comment: Usually people scale the image.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Do you mean scaling the image to a pre-defined range, e.g., [0,1]? Would you like to elaborate more?

Comment: Yes. Scale it to [0,1].

Comment: And subtract mean image.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your clarification.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few things that are done but really there is no set or fix set of pre-processing that is always done.

Here are some examples:

- Subtract the mean image,
- Divide by the variance (less common)
- Normalize the values
- if working with "real" images (like an image of people) then horizontal flips
- random crops
- translations

Comment: Hi Steven, regarding normalize the values, is that similar to what we usually do in statistics, normalize the pixel values to [0, 1]?

Comment: yeah by normalize I mean exactly that. The values between [0,1] whereas subtract mean and divide by variance would put you in the range [-1,1]